# Con’t connect STM32 board to laptop using ethernet cable. Ping works. Host application always shows Wifi IP and gateway, not static IP

Tags: stm32

I have a laptop with Wifi.
I directly connect a straight-through ethernet cable between my laptop and my custom STM32 board.
Using IPV4.

STM32 board with LWIP, set as server, IP 192.168.3.1, Gateway 192.168.3.0, Subnet mask 255.255.255.0, port 39
Laptop is client, set to IP 192.168.3.2, Gateway 192.168.3.0, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 in Control Panel->Network and Internet ->Network Connections, Ethernet Icon, Properties, Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
My STM32 board starts first, no issue with LWIP initialization.
Then I start Hercules application (from HW-group.com), it shows on “your PC network settings” the wifi IP, gateway and netmask. This is the problem.
When I ping from laptop on Hercules, it works fine.
When I try to connect from my laptop to STM32, it fails. Ethernet icon in Network connections has a red cross.

I had all this working before: I took my laptop home, came back, it stopped working.
When It was working, Hercules would show on “your PC network settings” IP 192.168.3.2, Gateway 192.168.3.0, Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0, and not the wifi IP/Gateway/Mask.
Also when it was working, Ethernet icon in Network connections would not have any red cross.

What am I doing wrong here?
Which settings I need to do so that Hercules app. Would show the static local IP 192.168.3.2 and not the wifi IP?
Anything that would allow me to connect my laptop to my STM32 board.
How to have/setup a wired LAN with static IP, that I can use to connect to my STM32 board

Answer (score 1):

192.168.3.0 is not an IP address for a device.

Comment: ... in a /24 network.

Comment: all this was working. I took my laptop home, bring it back it stopped working. when it was working, I would see on Hercules IP 192.168.3.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 and gateway 192.168.3.0. There is something I did on ethernet setting to have a local private LAN with static IP settings that I couldn't reproduce.

Comment: @YounesCHTIOUI What happened is unknown and beyond electronics. And still, your gateway address is invalid.

Comment: @Justme in /25 network it is not valid address. In /23 it is.

Comment: @Misaz Right. Off by one into wrong direction.